# Child Div's display:none is not working

Tags: html, css

**Display:none** is not working for the child div. How do I fix this problem?

*HTML*

```
<div class="parent">
    Hello
    <div class="child">
       Ola
    </div>
</div>
```

*CSS*

```
.parent {
    display:block;
}

.child {
    display:none;
}
```

In Chrome Developer Tools, child's display:none gets crossed out.

Comment: try closing the child class.  class="child"

Comment: Just clarified the question, there is stuff inside the divs, I just didn't write anything there for simplicity.

Comment: what is it replaced with? that should tell you what is overriding it in the css. There is probably another CSS selector or explicit style that is overriding the `display:none`

Comment: Here's a Fiddle for it... http://jsfiddle.net/N77aE/

Answer (score 2):

Found the error - had two display attributes in my actual code - not the simplified version of it here.
**silly mistake :P**

Answer (score 1):

Your HTML is incorrect and missing a closing quote `"`

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Actually It is correct (in my code) - I just made a mistake typing it in on here.